# Why doesn't Superfluid Circulation Vanish?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, superfluidity

In superfluid, the hydrodynamic velocity, $v$, is proportional to the gradient of the wavefunction phase: $\vec v= \frac \hbar m \nabla \phi$.
Given that, the circulation along a closed path, that cannot be shrunk to a point while remaining in the fluid, can be written as:
$$\oint \vec v \cdot d \vec l=\frac \hbar m\oint\nabla \phi \cdot d \vec l $$
What i don't understand is why, this closed path integral, doesn't vanish. Indeed, it can be proven that:
$$ \oint \nabla \phi \cdot d \vec l=2 \pi n$$
where $n$ is an integer.

I've found online [this explanation](https://ethz.ch/content/dam/ethz/special-interest/phys/theoretical-physics/cmtm-dam/documents/qg/Chapter_04.pdf). Basically, they say that circulation doesn't vanish because the path of integration isn't simply connected, and there can be a singularity inside the loop of integration. **However they also write: $\Delta \phi=2 \pi n$ and this is what confuses me, how is it possible that, the difference of the same function, evaluated in the same position, is not zero?**

Comment: Should $\phi$ be well-defined everywhere inside the area bounded by your integration curve, you can use the Stokes theorem to show that the circulation vanishes. You can only get a nonzero result if $\phi$ has a singularity somewhere. Indeed, the circulation will be nonzero if the integration path surrounds a superfluid vortex. At the vortex core, the magnitude of the superfluid condensate vanishes so $\phi$ is ill-defined. The quantization of the circulation follows from the fact that the phase of the superfluid condensate must change by a multiple of $2\pi$ when you go around a closed curve.

Comment: As to your question in bold, you should read "$\Delta\phi$" as the accumulated change of phase around the integration curve, not as a difference of some well-defined function between the initial and final points. The phase of a complex number is not a smooth, well-defined function on the entire complex plane.

Comment: I think your last comment is exactly about what i don't understand. I would be very happy if you give me a more detailed explanation about that. Thanks

Comment: I would need to know more precisely what you don't understand. Do you understand why the phase of a complex number is not a smooth single-valued function?

Comment: if $\phi(z)$ is the phase of a complex number, then, $\phi(x+i0^+)=0^+$ and $\phi(x-i0^-)=2\pi$. Do you mean this jump?

Comment: Good. Then it's obvious that you cannot naively apply the Stokes theorem to the line integral of $\nabla\phi$ to show that the integral is zero, since $\phi$ has a branch cut along the positive real semiaxis. A proper way to evaluate the integral would be to cover the integration domain with two patches, in each of which $\phi$ is a well-defined function, and then add up the results. This is how one does integration in differential geometry.